# How do I convert a json hash of hashes into a hash of arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, mustache

So If I have:

```
var hashof = {"stuff":
{"1": { "name": "fred"}},
{"2": { "name": "barney"}}
};
```

How can I use a javascript function to get:

```
var hashof = {"stuff":
["name" : "fred"],
["name" : "barney]
};
```

I want to be able to use the structure with mustache.js.

Comment: What you have (the first piece of code) is not valid JS: *"SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"* So what do you really have?

Comment: The unexpected token likely comes from the missing quote after "barney" - otherwise, it's valid

Comment: @Ryan Kinal: Ah you are right with the quote. But even with that it is not valid, the error is: *SyntaxError: Unexpected token :*. If I write it like this: `{"stuff": {"1": { "name": "fred"}}, {"2": { "name": "barney"}}}`, it should be pretty clear that this cannot be valid. There is the key missing between  `}},` and `{"2":`.

Comment: Right. I actually pointed that out in the edit to my answer, but assumed it would create an index of 0 (i.e. the next available numeric index). I guess I was wrong. +1

Answer (score 2):

The latter is  not possible. It is invalid. You probably wanted something like this:

```
var hashof = {"stuff": [
    {"name" : "fred"},
    {"name" : "barney"}
] };
```

The following should convert it like you need it:

```
function convert(input) {
    var output = [],
        key;

    for (key in input.stuff) {
        if (input.stuff.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            output[parseInt(key, 10)] = input.stuff[key];
        }
    }

    return {stuff: output};
}
```

Keep in mind, that the resulting array *may* be sparse. If you want to avoid this, you can use replace the line

```
output[parseInt(key, 10)] = input.stuff[key];
```

with

```
output.push(input.stuff[key]);
```

but you will not be able to preserve the original keys, then (it is not ensured, at least).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have associative arrays. The equivalent is a "hash" as you're calling it, or an object, which is what it actually is. The best you can hope for is this: `{"stuff": [{"name": "fred"}, {"name": "barney"}]}`

The following is untested, but should at least point you in the right direction.

```
var input = {"stuff": {"1": { "name": "fred"}}, {"2": { "name": "barney"}} },
    output = {}, key, innerKey;
for key in input
{
    output[key] = [];
    for innerkey in input[key]
    {
        output[key].push(input[key][innerKey]);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
It seems that the input object doesn't have the format I expected (or, in fact, the format I read when I read it the first time). It current has two properties:

- "stuff" is equal to `{"1": {"name": "fred"}}`
- There is another unkeyed item which is equal to `{"2": {"name": "barney"}}` (The key might be 0, I'm unsure on this point)

So, `input.stuff` only has one item, while `input[0]` has another item. If it were as follows, it would make more sense:

```
var input = {
    "stuff": {
        "1": {"name": "fred"},
        "2": {"name": "barney"}
    }
}
```

If this were the case, my code above would work. With the input given, it won't.

Comment: Thinking further about it, a conversion from the format in my edit to the format you wanted is kind of a moot point. The format in my edit is roughly equivalent to a 1-indexed array within an object.

Comment: Ryan- I'm using dot net JSONUTILS to wrangle json from an ms-access db (no choice) and, yes, the data is as you have represented it.  I'm just working with ff 3.6.12 error console and am getting no errors.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Ouch, that's an unfortunate requirement. Good luck! (And let me know how it goes. I work with .NET myself, though with SQL Server, rather than access).

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in javascript can only have numerical index, you need to be using Object to have associative array.

> An array is an ordered set of values
>   associated with a single variable
>   name. Note that you shouldn't use it
>   as an associative array, use Object
>   instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

I really should test this, but quick and dirty it looks like it will work...

```
 $.each(hashof.stuff, function(index, val) {
     hashof.stuff[index] = val.index;
  });
```

Comment: Looks like a strong argument for jquery (this is jquery, yes?).

Comment: Yes, I believe the original question had a jQuery tag.... but I've been wrong before.